# How does a "minimum number of items to be bought" factor into break even analysis?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, calculation, small-business

Let's say I am trying to find out how long it would take me to break even with a business venture.

My fixed costs are x (let's say $20,0000)

My Revenue per item sold is $50

My variable cost is $25 per item

Now here is the catch. I cannot buy less than 100 units of this item from the current manufacturer I am seeing.

Mathematically, how do I factor this into my break even calculation?

i.e.:

Is this the right way to do it:

Break-even quantity = (10,000)/[100 * (50-25)]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where did $10,000 in your calculation come from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an algebra problem, not a personal finance problem.

Answer (score 6):

A minimum purchase quantity just means that you need to round your result up to the nearest 100.

```
20,000 / (50-25) = 800
```

In your example it comes out evenly.
If we look at an example where it doesn't come out even, you'd round up:

```
20,000 / (50 - 21) = 689.66 = 690 (round up since can't sell fractional units)
```

And round that up to `700` due to purchase quantities.

For a slightly more complex and accurate approach, you'd then evaluate how many of the extras you had to buy due to the minimum purchase quantity would need to be sold:

```
(20,000 + (700 * 21)) / 50 = 694
```

So you'd have to sell `694` of the `700` purchased to break even.